# Best structure for nested dataset in python

Tags: python, nlp, dataset

a have an NLP problem at hand, where I need to create a nested dataset. I'm looking for a structure for my dataset that makes it easy for me to navigate through the dataset while coding.

My dataset consists of a context that will be divided into sub-contexts. Each sub-context will then be divided into sentences. And for each sentence in the subcontext, I will create three questions.

I thought about a nested dictionary that has the following structure:

```
ds = { doc1: {
              context1:{
                        S1:[q1,q2,q3],
                        S2:[q1,q2,q3],
                        ...
                        },
              context2:{
                        S1:[q1,q2,q3],
                        S2:[q1,q2,q3],
                        ...
                        },
       doc2: {
              context1:{
                        S1:[q1,q2,q3],
                        S2:[q1,q2,q3],
                        ...
                        },
              context2:{
                        S1:[q1,q2,q3],
                        S2:[q1,q2,q3],
                        ...
                        },
       ...
      }
```

doc = document, S = sentence, q = question

What do you think, are there better options?

Thx!

Comment: The only sentence in `context1` is `S1` and the only sentence in `context2` is `S2`? So there is only one sentence per subcontext?

Comment: @Stef there are multiple sentences in the contexts. Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the post to make it more clear.

Comment: The way you chose to present your data, with nested dictionaries, is good. It's a bit hard to recommend other ways. It's possible that depending on what you might want to do with the data, it might be interesting to first convert it to another structure, but only for specific tasks. Without more info about those tasks, we can only say that the way you chose to present the data looks good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process those kind of dataset in the python file, your idea is one of the solution. But, if you want to save those NL dataset for future, you might consider save it to XML or JSON formatting (into file [.xml] or [.json]).

```
<data>
    <part 1> text
        <context> text
            <sentences> text
                <q> text </q>
                <q> text </q>
                <q> text </q>
            </sentences>
        </context>
    </part 1>
        ...
    <part 3>
        <context>
            <sentences>
                <q></q>
                <q></q>
                <q></q>
            </sentences>
        </context>
    </part 3>
</data>

# this is XML example
```

XML and JSON is really common for nested dataset in my experience.